# What is the value in the enum ?

Tags: c, enums

As show in the following code, what is the difference between 0 and CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(0) in the cvmx_fau_reg_64_t?

```
#define CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(x) ((x <<3) + CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START)
typedef enum
{
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START          = 0, 
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END            = CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_64_t;
```

Comment: Note that _enum-constants_ are always type `int` and `enum` types themselves are not larger than `int`, too. Thus, for typical architectures with `int` having less than 64 bits, you run into problems using larger constants. ()It's just the names which look suspiciously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code as written, both values == 0. There is no difference in the actual value.

Comment: then what is the difference between CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START and CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END?

Comment: The way they are spelled. You basically have two identifiers that resolve to same thing.