# What is the value in the enum?

Tags: enums

As show in the following code, what is the difference between CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START and CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END in the cvmx_fau_reg_64_t?

```
`#define CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(x) ((x <<3) + CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START)
typedef enum
{
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START          = 0, 
    CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END            = CVMX_FAU_REG_64_ADDR(0),
} cvmx_fau_reg_64_t;`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the value in the enum ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539048/what-is-the-value-in-the-enum)

Comment: Yes, they are the same question, but I havn't got my answer yet, so I ask again.

Answer (score 0):

`CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START` is explicitly set to 0 with:
`CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START          = 0`

`CVMX_FAU_REG_64_END` is set to the function defined up top with an input of 0.

`0 << 3` Shifts 0 over by 3 bits, which is still 0, added to the value of `CVMX_FAU_REG_64_START`, which is also 0. (0 << 3) + 0 = 0, so they are both 0.